# getting error while installing gatsby - sudo npm install -g gatsby-cli

Tags: node.js, npm

**I am running this command:**

```
sudo npm install -g gatsby-cli
```

**Getting this error:**

```
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
```

**Node Version** - 12.22.5

**Npm Version** - 7.5.2

Comment: Please provide more details about npm and Node version. And don't install packages using sudo...

Comment: node -v
v12.22.5
npm -v
7.5.2

Comment: These are depreciation warnings not errors, may be gatsby team is well aware of, i got the same warnings a while back... Gatsby's end result is a static website so you shouldn't worry if gatsby team is still keeping the deprecated versions of some dependencies. Since you are not going to have these in your end product.